# Where add a couple of 4GB on Asus M4A785TD-M Evo

Tags: memory, motherboard

I bought 2 4GB RAM for Asus M4A785TD-M Evo motherboard.
I don't know where add them.
In the attached imagine you see the original 1GB RAM.
Should I add the 2 new 4GB in the empty slots or remove the 1GB
and substitute them with the new 4GB?
Thanks.
[image: Asus M4A785TD-M Evo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 GB today is a very small amount of memory today.

What I suggest (and what I do myself) is that you remove the 2 1 GB modules, put in the 2 4 GB modules (8 GB) and then you have two slots where you can still add (assuming your board will go to 16 GB).

This idea provides flexibility down the road.

Also you do not have to worry about matching anything. That is also helpful.

Comment: Indeed I know 2GB is too little amount of RAM. The mobo is told to hold a max of 4x4= 16GB so maybe I'll add two more 4GB and throw away the 1GB modules. Thanks.

Comment: Honestly I do not understand your "This idea provides flexibility down the road." Could you kindly clarify? thanks.

Comment: If you replace your existing memory (small modules) with bigger modules, you still have two slots left open. If your system can use more than 8 GB, you will be able to add memory into the empty slots. That is what I meant by flexibility. I hope that helps.